# using javascript onclick in an img to make a larger image show/hide

Tags: javascript, html

I can't figure out why this isn't working. It was working on my site previously and then quit. It's not working in jsfiddle so I'm assuming it's a coding problem. Here's a pared down version There are two full size images, one is set to display: block while the other display: none.

The javascript function is put in thumbnails of the pictures via onclick to change the full size pics to change the display style to either "none" or "block."

Here's the javascript:

```
function show_pic(this_one) {
    document.getElementById(current).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(this_one).style.display = "block";
    current = this_one;
}
```

Here's the html:

```
<img src='image1.jpg' id='img0' style='width: 100%; height: auto; border: solid #fff; box-sizing:border-box; display:block;' />
<img src='image2.jpg' id='img1' style='width: 100%; height: auto; border: solid #fff; box-sizing:border-box; display:none;' />

<img src='image1.jpg' style='height: 66px;  cursor: pointer;' onclick="show_pic('img0')" />
<img src='image2.jpg' style='height: 66px;  cursor: pointer;' onclick="show_pic('img1')" />
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hoodleehoo/qa9tf9e8/2/)

Comment: Just remove the script tags from the javascript area

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine. I opened JS fiddle and I edited the code to this:

```
var current = "img0";
function show_pic(this_one) {
    document.getElementById(current).style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(this_one).style.display = "block";
    current = this_one;
}
```

Just remove the the scripts tags since you are on a .js file.